# Primary Key Text File (Notepad++)

Tags: duplicates, text-files, primary-key

I was wondering if there was a way to set a `primary key` for text files using python. I am currently working on connecting a web scraper for the lottery to notepad++ text files to update the data sets. To prevent duplicates I think you need `unique id's`, and when it comes to lottery results the date seems like it would work. The reason I would be doing this is to prevent duplicates. Currently I am only able to add the new and old data together, and then overwrite the current file. If the answer is found, I will then add it into my other problem when it comes to connecting sublime, and notepad++ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217189/insert-ignore-text-file-notepad).

Comment: How is this related to Notepad++?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: On my computer the text files are stored on a drive, and exist in notepad++. If I were to update notepad++, it would also update the text files. When it comes to code, I have the web scraper, and a way to write to a text file all coded.

Comment: When it comes to setting a primary key, I haven't been able to find anything online, every time I look it up it gives me sql. I posted this question on here to see if it is at all possible to assign a primary key in a text file, or if any modules exist. I understand this website, and I am not asking people to write the code for me, but it seems like there are no answers for this problem. So if you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you have task scheduler(Windows), you can write to files the regular way.

```
with open("Filename.txt", "r") as f:
data = f.read()

with open("Filename.txt", "w") as f:
f.write('{}{}{}'.format(Fantasy5, '\n' if data else '', data))
f.close()
```

And then schedule the updates to the file. Using this there is no need for a primary key, and this prevents duplicates.